# How to find JIRA cases resolved or done by users in any given month or week?

Tags: jira

I have this JQL which gives me the details about the cases resolved/closed/done by me:

```
  assignee = currentUser() AND statusCategory = Done order by updated DESC
```

This works fine. However, my question is; How do I get the cases closed/done by perticular user in any given month or week?Any JQL query please? Also, Is there any query that can give me a count as well?

EDIT:
Below JQL not working as well.

```
      assignee = currentUser() AND assignee = userid1 AND assignee = userid2 AND statusCategory = Done order by updated DESC
```

Please note, in a restricted environment I may not able to use Plugins.

***One line requirement:*** I'm trying to get the number of tickets assigned to each team members (e.g. ***10 team members out of large 100 members***) and how many tickets they resolved in any given month( lets say, Dec 2021)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what Jira are you using Cloud or Software, and if you use any add-on, you may have a different set of options in the JQL and in the Gadgets, what I'm mentioning below works in both types of Jira without add-ons.

You can create different filters with your JQL to track the different times (My closed tickets last week, My closed tickets last month, etc)

e.g. if you add one of the following to your JQL

- `AND resolved >= startOfWeek()` you will have the tickets set to done in the current week (starting from this past Monday)
- `AND resolved >= startOfWeek(-1)` you will have the tickets set to done from last week (starting from its Monday) and the current week

You can use `startOfMonth()` or `startOfYear()` in the same way, and of course you can play with the operators to get and exact week, month or year if you wish. Or you can use `resolved > -1w`which gives you exactly the last 7 days. You can find additional examples [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver0813/advanced-searching-fields-reference-1027135325.html#Advancedsearchingfieldsreference-ResolvedResolutionDateresolutionDateResolved)

Let's say I save this JQL as "My closed tickets last week"
`assignee = currentUser() AND statusCategory = Done AND AND resolved >= startOfWeek(-1) AND resolved < startOfWeek() order by updated DESC` to get only the tickets resolved last week

Now you can't get the amount of tickets from the JQL itself, I mean you can run the filter and see the amount of tickets it returns. I'm assuming you want to have a place where you see at once the amount of tickets closed last week, last month or last year all together.
What you can do is grouping those tickets in Gadgets in a Dashboard.

Unfortunately Jira doesn't have a wide range of reporting tools, so if you don't use any add-on you will have to settle for what you have available.

Once you saved your filter, you can follow the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver/saving-your-search-as-a-filter-939938748.html) if you are not familiar with it
You can go to your Dashboard normally here `https://<your Jira URL>/secure/Dashboard.jspa` and add one of these gadgets that would give you the total count of tickets based on the filter:

- **Issue Statistic**, if you set it up like this
  [image]
  it will show this
  [image]
- **Two Dimensional Filter Statistic**, if you set it up like this
  [image]
  it will show this
  [image]
- **Pie Chart**, if you set it up like this
  [image]
  it will show this
  [image]

They are not ideal, but they give you a number you can looks at, you can have multiple of them for each filter you create, and use the same for other statuses as well, and you can adjust them in case you need to create these sort of reports including multiple people not just like yourself.

If having add-ons is an option for you [EazyBI](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211051/eazybi-reports-and-charts-for-jira?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview) is made to cope with the lack of reporting features in Jira. It has reports of any sort, but the learning curve can be medium/high. Once you create your reports there, you can show them in a Jira Dashboard as well as other Gadgets.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse.Im using web vertion( i think cloud one) and Jira v8.13.8. However, most of the JQL is not working here.. Even, this does not return any result "My closed tickets last week" assignee = currentUser() AND statusCategory = Done AND AND resolved >= startOfWeek(-1) AND resolved < startOfWeek() order by updated DESC" .

Comment: Are you running exactly this filter? `assignee = currentUser() AND statusCategory = Done AND AND resolved >= startOfWeek(-1) AND resolved < startOfWeek() order by updated DESC` ? If so, do you have any ticket assigned to yourself where the statusCategory has been set to Done between Dec 27th and Jan 2nd? If you don't have any ticket that match those criteria this is the reason why it's empty. Try creating a ticket today, assign it to yourself, and set the statusCategory to Done. Then use this JQL `assignee = currentUser() and statusCategory = done and  resolved >= startOfWeek()`

Comment: Hi @Graziella - Thank you for suggestion to use 2D filter stat view. I think, I can use it. However, the problem is, if I use few users( lets say 10 users) out of 100 users from a big team in my JQL is not showing any result.  I would like to use specific userID's ( 10 people) in my JQL and trying to get the result for 10 members only. How to write JQL for 10 users considering a monthly view? Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `=` use `in`. I'm not sure `statusCategory` is the field you should use try `status` instead. I suggest you to keep this documentation in hand https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver0813/advanced-searching-1027135313.html, there are many links there called "<something> reference page" that can guide you in the future. In this case you should have something like this to get all the closed tickets in December assigned to those 10 people `assignee in (user1, user2, user3, etc ) AND status = Done AND AND resolved >= startOfMonth(-1) AND resolved < startOfMonth() `

Comment: If still doesn't work. Open one of the tickets you want to get, and check each field you are using in the filter. Match each field names and values between the ticket and the filter to be sure you are using the right fields and the right values. This is the rule of thumb when creating JQL